# Adding pictures to a Modern Page comments

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-pages, comments

we have enabled Comment on modern pages, but i am not sure if we can upload a picture as part of a comment body?

[image]

Comment: Don't think you can...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In currently, it is not supported to add picture in the comment body in modern page.

As a workaround, we can add the picture links in the body.